# Save customer custom attributes without clear caches

Tags: magento2, customer

Every time I need to clear cache when saving customer attributes using the following code.

$customerData->setCustomAttribute('custom_name', $name);
$customermodel->updateData($customerData);

what is the proper solution to save customer custom attributes in Magento2?

Answer (score 0):

use Factory and try the following code

```
$customerData->setCustomAttribute('custom_name', $name);            
$customerModel = $this->customerFactory->create()->updateData(
        $customerData
    );
```

Comment: I tried this way but still need to clear cache

$customerFactory= $ob->create('Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory');
            $customerData->setCustomAttribute('custom_name', $name);            
$customerModel = $customerFactory->create()->updateData(
        $customerData
    );
$customerResource = $objectManager->create ('\Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerFactory')->create();
$customerResource->saveAttribute($customerModel, 'custom_name');